# Datatable row selection single setting through backing bean not working properly

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using Prime faces 3.5 data table with selection mode as single, the data table shows up list of domains in an edit group, while the page loading the primary domain should be selected in the data table this setting is done through the backing bean. 
But the the problem is that the selection not working properly. For example, if I click edit group first time the primary selection is getting selected then close dialog and then again edit the same group the row selection is not getting selected.

```
        <p:dataTable id="dialog_DomainList"
            value="#{domainGrpDetailBean.domainAliasVOModel}" var="v"
            rowKey="#{v.domainId}" selection="#{domainGrpDetailBean.selectedPrimaryDomain}"
        scrollable="#{domainGrpDetailBean.domainScrollFlag}"
        scrollRows="5" scrollHeight="70" editable="true"
        editingRow="#{v.newAdded}" resizableColumns="true">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                listener="#{domainGrpDetailBean.onEditDomainAlias}"
                oncomplete="updateDomainAliasTable();"
                update=":group_DialogForm:msgs" />
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['domaingroup.datatabel.header.ids']}"
            width="10%">
            <h:outputText value="#{v.domainId}"
             rendered="#{v.domainId gt -1}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column
                headerText="#{msg['domaingroup.datatabel.header.primary']}"
                selectionMode="single" width="10%">
        </p:column>
        <p:column
                headerText="#{msg['domaingroup.datatabel.header.domainstatus']}"
                width="20%">
            <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{v.statusString}" />
                    </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{v.status}"
                        style="width:98%; text-align:left">
            <f:selectItems
                        value="#{domainGrpDetailBean.domainStatusList}"
                var="status" itemLabel="#{status}" itemValue="#{status}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
```

How do I set the selected row setting through backing bean?

Answer (score 1):

You can force this with code like this:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="@this"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" process="@this"/>
```